# Force Show the latest Chatter Feed Item relating to a record

Tags: apex, chatter, custom-button, feeditem

Not really a question but something cool that might belong here, we had a customer that has a round robin process for lead assignment driven by a button. We from there are calling a hidden Visualforce page which runs a class updating the record with the appropriate new OwnerId.

Now they wanted an indication that this roundrobin process was successful without having to scroll down to the OwnerField (which they did not want to relocate) or the field history related list. So I found you can use chatter to achieve this instead.

Adding this URL parameter to our redirect ?fid='ChatterFeedIdvalue' i.e. ?fId=0D5N0000000X22JKAS forces the chatter feed open and shows a cool value called 'This update' right at the top of the page. i.e.

![Chatter Feed]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afQY2.png